# In Codeigniter how to improve Rest Web service Mysql performance?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, codeigniter, rest

I have a table which has a column to store Facebook id , message etc... now i have 1000 records.
This is my table structure.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_notification` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `facebook_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `preference_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `notification_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `message` text NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '0 means unread 1 means read',
  `timestamp` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `created_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `facebook_id` (`facebook_id`),
  KEY `status` (`status`),
  KEY `timestamp` (`timestamp`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

I have written a Rest Web service using code-igniter like by passing Facebook id i am generating a list of message based on that Facebook id. The thing is its taking too much time to load in rest Client (1000 millisecond) and mobile .

The Query i am using to generate result like this,

```
"SELECT id, facebook_id,`notification_id`, `message`, `status`,preference_id,timestamp FROM `user_notification` WHERE  facebook_id='" . $facebook_id . "'  and timestamp >='" . $timestamp . "' and status!='2' ORDER BY timestamp DESC"
```

Is their any way to improve the loading time?

i tried stored procedure also no improvement.

Comment: You can implement memcache

Comment: Start by using the right types: timestamp should be of kind time, date, datetime. Is facebook_id an integer? Choose int as type. For what do you need status? Your description says 0 or 1, but you are searching for not 2. Also here, use the right type: Boolean

Comment: try to use paging on data or load data on scroll by chunks and also set index on table.

Answer (score 1):

This composite index will be more efficient:

```
INDEX(facebook_id, timestamp)
```

[*Discussion here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) and [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index1).